# smartgwt window headercontrols position

Tags: smartgwt

Is it possible to choose the position of the different header component position?

```
window.setHeaderControls(dynamicFormName, contextMenuButton, HeaderControls.MINIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.CLOSE_BUTTON);
```

I need to have the dynamicFormName on the left and the others on the right.

Answer (score 0):

just adding HeaderControls.HEADER_LABEL did the trick

```
window.setHeaderControls(dynamicFormName, HeaderControls.HEADER_LABEL, contextMenuButton, HeaderControls.MINIMIZE_BUTTON, HeaderControls.CLOSE_BUTTON);
```